# How to fetch and sort multiple model types with SwiftData?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I'm trying to create a SwiftUI view where objects of different types will be displayed in the same list and sorted based on a common attribute, similar to the iOS Photos app, where photos and videos are displayed in the same grid and sorted by their creation date.

To do this, I need an efficient way to retrieve a sorted collection of mixed-type items from SwiftData. Unfortunately, SwiftData seems to only support fetching and sorting records of the same type.

I have considered the following approaches:

- **Entity inheritance:** <s>Using entity inheritance is discouraged in Core Data</s>, and SwiftData doesn't seem to support entity inheritance.
- **Fetch records of each model type separately, then combine and sort them in memory:** I will have to fetch all records ahead of time (for sorting) and won't be able to use lazy loading. This won't work when the number of records becomes too large.

How can I efficiently fetch and sort mixed model types in SwiftData?

Here is the example code for my problem:

### Model

```
import SwiftData


protocol Media {
    var creationDate: Date { get set }
}

@Model
final class Photo: Media {
    var creationDate: Date
    var isLivePhoto: Bool
    
    init() {
        self.creationDate = Date()
        self.isLivePhoto = Bool.random()
    }
}

@Model
final class Video: Media {
    var creationDate: Date
    var duration: Int
    
    init() {
        self.creationDate = Date()
        self.duration = Int.random(in: 0..<10)
    }
}
```

### View

```
import SwiftUI


struct MediaListView: View {
    @Query(sort: \Photo.creationDate, order: .reverse) var photos: [Photo]
    @Query(sort: \Video.creationDate, order: .reverse) var videos: [Video]
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                // How can I display a list of Photo and Video, sorted by creationDate, without loading all records into memory?
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {               
            // Add random examples to data store
            for _ in 0...10 {
                if Bool.random() {
                    modelContext.insert(Photo())
                }
                else {
                    modelContext.insert(Video())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MediaListView()
        }
        .modelContainer (for: [Photo.self, Video.self])
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Entity inheritance is the best way to do this. Not sure why you say it's discouraged, many Apple apps use it eg Notes.

Comment: @malhal I thought it was discouraged because many answers on SO and articles cautioned against using it, like [this article](https://www.marisibrothers.com/2016/01/5-tips-when-using-core-data-in-swift-2.html). And SwiftData apparently doesn't support entity inheritance at the moment.

Comment: That article is wrong. I would guess their performance problem was because they forgot to add indicies for the attributes they were querying.

Comment: @KhắcHào do you find the solution for this?

Comment: @PratyushPratik I haven't found a solution for this. SwiftData is quite new so I guess this use case isn't supported yet.